# How to find type of PCI slots on windows server

Tags: windows, wmi, pci

I want to get PCI slot type information on windows similar to linux.
On Linux when I run
`dmidecode -t slot`
I see output similar to

```sh
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.1 present.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI1
    Type: x16 PCI Express 3 x16
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 6
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:01:00.0
```

On Windows I tried both `Win32_SystemSlot()` WMI library call which shows some data but not the type of the slot like 'x16 PCI Express 3 x16' similar to what I see using linux OS on the same server.

```c
    wmi.WMI().Win32_SystemSlot()

    BusNumber = 65535;
    Caption = "System Slot";
    ConnectorType = {0};
    CreationClassName = "Win32_SystemSlot";
    CurrentUsage = 3;
    Description = "System Slot";
    DeviceNumber = 80;
    FunctionNumber = 0;
    MaxDataWidth = 8;
    Name = "System Slot";
    PMESignal = TRUE;
    SegmentGroupNumber = 65535;
    Shared = FALSE;
    SlotDesignation = "PCI1";
    Status = "OK";
    SupportsHotPlug = FALSE;
    Tag = "System Slot 0";
    VccMixedVoltageSupport = {2};
```

I tried to look up the meaning/mapping for `ConnectorType = {0};` from the output above but that maps to unknown type as per the document below.

https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_systemslot

How can I get the `Type: x16 PCI Express 3 x16` information for a PCI system slot on Windows?